# Stop an app from working for a client

Tags: iphone

I have written an iPhone App for a client and they are using my ad hoc provisioning profile.  If I wanted to stop them from using the App e.g. they don't pay etc and disappear.

Could I just remove the provisioning profile from the developer site and would this cause that app to stop working?

Comment: Your provisioning profile will expire eventually. And contracts are how you protect yourself, not through an API.

Comment: @Abizern -- contracts only work within country borders.  If a client in another country decides not to pay, the programmer is usually stuck with very little recourse.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann If that were true, there wouldn't be a lot of international trade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once the app is installed on your client's device, it will continue to work.

What I do for my own ADHOC apps is to have a text file on a private web server that my ADHOC apps "ping" (e.g. via `[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL]`) and if the contents of that text file say something like `"INVALID"`, I `exit(-1)` the app.  This is usually a good thing to do with clients who might potentially stiff or avoid paying their bills.

If you do something like what I am describing above, **MAKE CERTAIN** to remove that code prior to putting it up on the Apple Store.  Apple can reject your app for doing a stunt like that.

Comment: in this case you have to handle if you are not able to connect to private server.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way, keep the profile expiration date as min as possible. Once the ad-hoc provisioning profile on device expires, the application will not run ( will get terminated as it starts ).

Comment: is it possible to modify (or shorten) the profile expiration dates for ADHOC profiles?